# What checks should be used when installling non-repository or offline software?

Tags: security, malware, offline, aptoncd

Case 1) Let's say some software isn't available in the repositories and you have to download it from a website and install it.

Case 2) You have downloaded a DRM free paid software but can no longer download the latest version (like Humble bundle without steam keys) and it has been sitting there forever and you find the need to use it again, but are not sure if it has been infected and you can't take a chance.

Case 3) You backed up your software to a USB storage and are not sure if it has been modified or infected but want to install it.

Case 4) You get software from a friend. You want to install it.

What can be done in the above cases to reduce the risk of malware?

Also please don't point that the chances of getting malware on linux are less.

Answer (score 0):

Virus checker - run the code through [Avast](http://www.avast.com/linux-home-edition),  [AVG](http://free.avg.com/us-en/download.prd-alf), [BitDefender](http://www.bitdefender.com/business/antivirus-for-unices.html) (must select "Evaluation version"), [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php), and, of course, ClamTK (install from Synaptic).

How long has it been out there? How long has the maintainer been out there?  Do a web search for complaints or bug reports. Old bug reports are a good sign... it's been around a while.

Download the source and recompile it. If the compilation matches the download, chances are low that it contains malware.

You may wish to enable [SELinux](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/001nov04/features/selinux/), see [more](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/ch09.html), see [home page](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux).

Best of all, review the code or ask a Linux guru to look at it.